# I have two iCloud accounts. How do I address all backups to one single account?

Tags: icloud

I have two devices (Iphone 6plus and Ipad air) with IOS 9 and one macbook pro (Yosemite). I also have two iCloud accounts. I want to backup all my data in just one iCloud and setup everything to backup in the main one where I have an storage plan. However, I continue receiving messages from the "unwanted" iCloud account, telling me that my store (basic 5GB) is over, meaning that something is still being backup in this account. What can I do to solve this? thanks for your support

Comment: Can't you just sign out of the account?

Answer (score 1):

You can sign in to each account in turn at https://iCloud.com and delete backups or examine the storage for each. Once both are under their respective quoaptas, the warnings will go away.